# How to send array of dates to REST API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a UI component where users can add a selection of dates to an "event" object by clicking an "Add Date" button to add another row to a table.

Once the user has selected the appropriate date, they would then click the Save button and the form would be submitted to my corresponding REST API with the request payload containing the array named "events".
E.g.

```
{
    name: "placeholder",
    events: [
         '2018-12-12',
         '2018-12-14',
         '2018-12-15'
    ]
}
```

However, instead the payload being sent from Angular looks like this:

```
{
    name: "placeholder",
    event0: '2018-12-12',
    event1: '2018-12-14',
    event2: '2018-12-15',
}
```

Do you know how I can produce the first payload instead?

This is my angular HTML template:

```
<form #BookingForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveBooking(BookingForm)">
    <div *ngFor="let event of booking.events; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="Extra date" [(ngModel)]="event" name="event{{i}}">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="addExtraDate()">Add Extra Date</button>
</form>
```

Angular TS code:

```
export class Booking {
    name: string;
    events: array;
}


public booking: any = new Booking;

public addExtraDate(): void {
        this.booking.events.push({});
    }

public saveBooking(form: any): void {
        var item = form.value;
        console.log(item);
        this.bookingService
            .addBooking(item)
            .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: is `this.booking.extra_dates` referring to the object your showing at the beginning?

Comment: Hi, Did you tried changing name of your inputs as array?
 name="extra_date[{{i}}]">

Comment: @ams Sorry yes this.booking.extra_dates is referencing the object at the beginning. I've updated the question to make it consistent.

Comment: @Padhu Just tried that but same problem

Comment: How is your form connected to "name"? Show the code building the form...

Comment: Updated question with the property and instantiated class that's used with the form

Comment: were you try [(ngModel)]="events[i]"?

Comment: Yes, if I try that then the payload becomes: { events[0]: '2018-12-15', events[1]: '2018-12-17' }